# What is a bare minimum microservice architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices

I am currently exploring the concept of microservices architecture and trying to understand the nuances of its definition, especially when compared to a monolithic architecture.

My specific question is: **At what point in the spectrum of a full monolith versus a full microservice architecture can a service be truly considered a microservice?**

To put this into context, consider a three-tier application where each tier has its own separate codebase and runs on a separate server:

**Frontend**: A Node.js application with a React front end.
**Backend**: A Django application handling business logic and server-side operations.
**Database**: A separate Database service (e.g., PostgreSQL, MongoDB, etc.), which both the front end and back end communicate with.
Each of these components is developed and deployed independently. However, they are tightly integrated in terms of overall functionality and perhaps share a common data model. But they are loose enough that they can be upgraded independently more often than not.

In this scenario, can each of these components (Node.js frontend, Django backend, Database service) be considered individual microservices? If not, what additional characteristics or modifications would be needed to categorize them as microservices?

I am particularly interested in understanding the bare minimum criteria that differentiates a microservice from a simple modular component in a multi-tier architecture. Examples or references to best practices in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most terms have fuzzy boundaries; there isn't a clear line between "socks" and "shoes", for example, and although most socks/shoes are either obviously socks or obviously shoes, there's no specific criterion or set of criteria that applied to a sock/shoe will always tell you which it is, and given a sufficiently borderline case, different people will disagree.

I think almost everyone can agree that the tiers in a standard three-tier architecture are not "microservices"; rather, a microservice architecture involves multiple backend components that accept service-to-service calls (probably RPC calls, though RESTful and message-queue architectures are also possible). But there's no specific number or size or homogeneity of such services that marks a sudden transition from "not microservices" to "yes microservices". The boundary is fuzzy, and unavoidably subjective.